# Passing several variables to a method in a rest service with node JS

Tags: rest, variables, service, methods

please I need to pass several variables to my rest service implemented with node JS, for now I have this:

Here I am passing just one variable, but I need more variables.

```
app.get('/announcement/:search', announce.findAllBysearch);
```

**Method Implementation:**

```
exports.findAllBysearch = function(req, res) {
    var srch = req.params.search;//Here is receiving the variable
}
```

I am using it like this:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            data: '{}',
            cache:false,
            url: "http://server:4000/announce/"+search,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            processdata: true,
            success: function(data) {
}
});
```

I would like to do this:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            data: '{}',
            cache:false,
            url: "http://server:4000/announce/"+search+'/'+page,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            processdata: true,
            success: function(data) {
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.VERB) show that you can use regular expressions or multiple variables.  Possibly something like this where you would use `req.params.search` and `req.params.page`:

```
app.get('/announcement/:search/page/:page', announce.findAllBysearch);
```

or with a regex where you would use `req.params[0]` and `req.params[1]`:

```
app.get(/^\/announcement/(\w+)(?:\/page\/(\w+))$/, announce.findAllBysearch)
```